# How to find button with predicate under UITests in Xcode7?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.1beta

I need to access following button:

[image]

This line works fine:

```
app.buttons["Reorder 1, $27 000, LondonStreet, ok, Pending"]
```

but this don't:

```
app.buttons.elementMatchingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "accessibilityTitle BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", "Reorder 1"))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When finding elements via predicates you must use the [`XCUIElementAttributes` Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes). For this example, I don't think `title` will actually work, but try using [`label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500692-label) (which should map to `accessibilityLabel`).

For some reason the `%@` format option doesn't seem to work in Swift. Also note the extra single quotes around "Reorder 1".

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH[cd] 'Reorder 1'")
let button = app.buttons.elementMatchingPredicate(predicate)
```

Comment: Maybe you know the answer for this also?:-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522465/how-to-open-url-in-safari-and-the-get-back-to-the-app-under-uitests-in-xcode-7

Comment: can use `identifier` instead of `label` if you use the accessibility identifier instead of the label